# How to show additional info in a vaadin combobox selection list?

Tags: combobox, vaadin

I'd like to have a combobox where there is a lot of information in the list to select from or search but only parts of it are shown after selection.

For example when the user starts typing "raf" the combobox should show a list like this:

- RA - Raffael (raffael@example.com)
- HU - Hugo (hugo@rafferty.xyz)

After selecting the entry "Raffael" only "RA" should be shown in the combobox.

I need that because of the limited space for the combobox in my application. So the combobox should not be wider than needed to hold some characters but the list to select from may be much wider. Is there an easy way to achieve that? Or which function i have to overwrite in combobox to set the text line after the selection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with a standard Vaadin ComboBox without custom client side coding.

Comment: Thanks. I found a kind of solution by overriding getItemCaption and returning the short version if its equal the value of the field and returning the long otherwise. It is nether a nice nor a fully working solution. I guess i have to do some client side coding.